# How to check if a JSON Array object contains a Key

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

```
{
  "myJSONArrayObject": [
    {
      "12": {}
    },
    {
      "22": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the above JSON Array object. How can I check if **`myJSONArrayObject`** has a particular key?

This approach is not working :

```
let myIntegerKey = 12;

if (myJSONArrayObject.hasOwnProperty(myIntegerKey))
      continue;
```

It seems to return false when it contains a key and true when it doesn't.

Comment: If it's possible, maybe you can use regular objects, so `[{ "id": 12, "value": {} }, { "id": 22, "value": {} }]`. Way easier to search/transform than when every object inside the array has different keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myJSONArrayObject` is an array. It doesn't have `12` as a property (Unless there are 12+ items in the array)

So, check if [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the objects in the array have `myIntegerKey` as a property

```
const exists = data.myJSONArrayObject.some(o => myIntegerKey in o)
```

or if `myIntegerKey` is always an *own* property

```
const exists = data.myJSONArrayObject.some(o => o.hasOwnProperty(myIntegerKey))
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const data={myJSONArrayObject:[{"12":{}},{"22":{}}]},
      myIntegerKey = 12,
      exists = data.myJSONArrayObject.some(o => myIntegerKey in o);

console.log(exists)
```

Comment: This is great!
Is there a way to check not just the key, but a key:value pairing with this method?

Answer (score 0):

`"myJSONArrayObject"` is an array so you have to check `hasOwnProperty` on each of it's elements:

```
let myIntegerKey = 12;

for (var obj in myJSONArrayObject) {
  console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(myIntegerKey));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  myJSONArrayObject: [
    {
      12: {},
    },
    {
      22: {},
    },
  ],
};

const myIntegerKey = '12';
const isExist = obj.myJSONArrayObject.findIndex((f) => { return f[myIntegerKey]; }) > -1;
console.log(isExist);
```

You can make it faster with `every()`

```js
const obj = {
  myJSONArrayObject: [
    {
      22: {},
    },
    {
      12: {},
    },
  ],
};

const myIntegerKey = '12';

const isExist = !obj.myJSONArrayObject
  .every((f) => {
    return !f[myIntegerKey];
  });
console.log(isExist);
```

> **Note**: Here the key name (`12: {},`) doesn't rely on `typeof myIntegerKey`, `12` and `'12'` both will return `true`.

Comment: Misunderstood your comment, thought you meant the other way around, that it Does matter sometimes and using this code prevents it.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct method to retrieve the object by a key is to use [JavaScript bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation). Use the `find` method to iterate over the array, also.

```js
const obj = {
  myJSONArrayObject: [{
      12: {},
    },
    {
      22: {},
    },
  ],
};

const myIntegerKey = 12;
const myObject = obj.myJSONArrayObject.find(item => item[myIntegerKey]);
console.log("exists", myObject !== undefined);
```